# Divisor problem: find the fallacy!

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, divisors-multiples

The following approach to the divisor problem (that is, the problem of estimating $D(x) = \sum_{n\leq x} d(n)$, where $d(n)$ is the number of divisors of $n$; more precisely, we are meant to bound the error term $\Delta(x)$ in $D(x) = x \log x + x (2 \gamma - 1) + \Delta(x)$) gives a result that is too good, and must hence be mistaken. However, I can't see where the error is. Can you?

We will start from the following result of Wigert's (Thm 7.15 in Titchmarsh's Theory of the Zeta Function): for $z\to 0$ with $|\arg z|\leq \alpha$, $\alpha < \pi/2$,
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty d(n) e^{-n z} = \frac{\gamma - \log z}{z} + \frac{1}{4} + O(|z|).$$
(In fact, Wigert gave a more precise expression - a series development $\sum_{n=0}^{N-1} b_n z^{2 n + 1} + O(|z|^{2 N})$ instead of $O(|z|)$).

We will proceed as follows. Let $g(x)$ be a $C^2$ (or smooth) function equal to $e^x$ for $0\leq x\leq 1$, equal to $0$ for $x>1+\epsilon$, and going down from $e$ to $0$ as $x$ goes from $1$ to $1+\epsilon$. (What $g(x)$ equals for $x<0$ is immaterial.) Clearly we can bound
$$\sum_{n=1}^x d(n) \leq D_g(x) := \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} d(n) e^{-n/x} g(n/x).$$
We can get a lower bound in exactly the same way by changing the scale by a factor of $(1+\epsilon)$; the gap between the two estimates (to be obtained in what follows) should be small (namely, $O(\epsilon x \log x)$).

Now $\widehat{g}(t)$ is a nice function, with $\widehat{g}(t) = O(\min(1,1/t))$ for every $t$, and $\widehat{g}(t)$ decaying very rapidly for $|t|>10/\epsilon$, say. We should be safely able to invert summation and integration:
$$D_g(x) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \widehat{g}(t) \sum_{n=1}^\infty d(n) e^{-n/x} e(t n/x) dt.$$
By Wigert's result with $z = (1-2\pi i t)/x$,
$$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty d(n) e^{n/x} e(t n/x) = \frac{x}{1 - 2 \pi i t} (\gamma + \log x - \log(1-2\pi i t)) + \frac{1}{4} + O\left(\frac{1+|t|}{x}\right).$$
Using our bounds on $\widehat{g}(t)$, we obtain, from right to left:

- An error term of size $O(1/\epsilon x)$,
- A term $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\widehat{g}(t)}{4} dt = g(0) = 1,$$
- The main terms: the larger one is
  $$x (\log x + \gamma) \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\widehat{g}(t)}{1 - 2 \pi i t} dt,$$ which, by Plancherel and the fact that the Fourier transform of $1/(1-2\pi i t)$ is the Heaviside function times $e^{-x}$, equals
  $$x (\log x + \gamma) \int_0^\infty g(x) e^{-x} dx = 
   x ( \log x + \gamma) \cdot (1+O(\epsilon)).$$
  The term $$- x \int_{-\infty}^\infty \widehat{g}(t) \frac{\log(1-2\pi i t)}{1 - 2\pi i t} dt$$ is a little harder to estimate (the Fourier transform of $h(t) = \log(1-2\pi i t)/(1-2\pi i t)$ is not trivial to figure out, and diverges at the origin -- logarithmically it would seem) but the following detour seems to work: by Plancherel,
  $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \widehat{g}(t) \frac{\log(1-2\pi i t)}{1 - 2\pi i t} dt = \int_0^\infty g(x) \widehat{h}(x) dx = \int_0^1 e^x \widehat{h}(x) dx + \int_1^{1+\epsilon} (g(x)-1) \widehat{h}(x) dx.$$
  By Plancherel again,
  $$\int_0^1 e^x \widehat{h}(x) dx = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{1-2\pi i t} - 1}{(1-2\pi i t)^2} \log(1-2\pi i t) dt,$$
  and this integral would seem to be $1-\gamma$ (confession: I integrated numerically). Clearly $$\int_1^{1+\epsilon} (g(x)-1) \widehat{h}(x) dx = O(\epsilon).$$

Thus we end up obtaining $$D_g(x) = x (\log x + 2 \gamma - 1) \cdot (1+ O(\epsilon)) + 1 + O\left(\frac{1}{\epsilon x}\right),$$
and thus
$$D(x) = x (\log x + 2 \gamma - 1) \cdot (1+ O(\epsilon)) + 1 + O\left(\frac{1}{\epsilon x}\right).$$
Then we could set $\epsilon=1/x$, and obtain $$D(x) = x (\log x + 2 \gamma - 1) + O(\log x),$$ which is insane, and provably wrong: it is known that the error term cannot be that small.

Where is the error?

Comment: Mustn't $\epsilon$ be independent on $x$?

Comment: Not really - though one thing that I can see is that the quality of the bound from Wigert may depend on $\alpha$, and we should take $\alpha = \pi/2 - \epsilon/10$. That may be the key - but, beyond that, do you see a reason why $\epsilon$ has to be independent of $x$?

Comment: From scanning the proof of the Wigert bound, I think the dependence on $\alpha$ is something like $O(\lvert z\rvert+(\pi/2-\alpha)^{-1}\lvert z\rvert^2)$. A quick look-over suggests that this means your final bound should actually be $O(1/\epsilon^2x)$, so take $\epsilon=x^{-2/3-\epsilon}$ and a final bound of $O(x^{1/3+\epsilon})$, which looks more right, as it matches the Voronoi bound.

Comment: If it is really $O(|z|+(\pi/2-\alpha)^{-1} |z|^2)$, how is the final bound not $O(\epsilon x \log x) + O(\epsilon^3/x^2)$, which, for $\epsilon = x^{-3/4}$, would yield the manifestly insane bound $O(x^{1/4} \log x)$?

Comment: I think the proof in Titchmarsh yields $O(c|z|)$, where $c=\int_{-\infty}^\infty|\Gamma(-1+it)\zeta^2(-1+it)|e^{|t|(\alpha-\pi/2)}\,dt$. Standard bounds give that $c\asymp(\pi/2-\alpha)^{-5/2}$.

Comment: Well, my previous comment needs a small fix as $\Gamma(-1+it)$ blows up at $t=0$. Restrict the integral to $t>1$, say.

Comment: It would be clearer to put an index on the different quantities denoted by $\epsilon$.

Comment: I'm getting the same as @GH for $\sigma=-1$. More generally, when the line of integration is shifted to $\sigma = - r$, I get a term $O(\epsilon^{-(3/2+r)} |z|^r)$,(in addition to a polynomial on $z$ whose coefficients are indepdendent of $\epsilon$) and hence ultimately an error term $O(\epsilon^{-3/2-2r}/x^r)$. Adding it to the error term $O(\epsilon x \log x)$ (and to the polynomial on $z$, we see that, in the limit as $r\to \infty$, the exponent of $x$ tends to $1/2$, and thus we obtain $O_\epsilon(x^{1/2+\epsilon})$.

Comment: ... which of course is fine, but also disappointing. I was hoping that the argument, once fixed, would match the Voronoi bound. Perhaps that's still doable by being a little cleverer. Bedtime for me now.

Comment: Is there really nothing in the literature with a better error dependence than Wigert's bound?

Comment: Well, there's Voronoi, as in section 4.5 of Iwaniec-Kowalski. Obviously (say I to myself).

Comment: I just double-checked. If you use Voronoi instead of Wigert, you get a final result in the order of $x^{1/3}$. That's nice, as it matches... Voronoi :).

Comment: Ah, you don't need Voronoi at all. Modularity (facepalm).